# How can I  map the right Super key to open a specific appindicator's menu?

Tags: indicator, panel, shortcut-keys, pointers

For example, I have the Classic Menu Indicator installed, and I'd like for the menu to fly out after I hit the right Super key.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise your desktop Icons and Settings, Windows placement and Focus and change Panel attributes. It even has the "fly-out" menu setting you were asking about.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager python-compizconfig compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-bcop compiz-fusion-plugins-main compizconfig-backend-gconf
```

[image]

[Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/)

Comment: I've looked through compiz settings, but I can't see how you bind a key to a particular appindicator menu.